# Stored procedure doesn't call during the event scheduler running in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I wrote a event scheduler in mysql database to run a stored procedure every day at 23:59. But it is not working properly. The code of my event scheduler is as follows:

```
create definer =`root`@`%` EVENT `day_close_event` 
on schedule  every 1 hour starts '2016-06-21 23:00:00' on completion preserve enable 
do 
call sp_day_close_process();
```

Is there any problem the above code? If any problem please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the user `'root'@'%'` exists.

```
CREATE definer = 'root'@'%' EVENT day_close_event 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-06-21 23:59:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE do call sp_day_close_process();
```